# Bash command prompt with virtualenv and git branch

Tags: git, bash, virtualenv, command-prompt

I previously had my bash command prompt displaying the last two directories of my present working directory and my git branch if I am inside of a git repo. I starting adding some projects inside virtual environments and when I was working on those, my command prompt settings stopped working.

I've managed to get the virtualenv and my current directory displayed, but I'm still not able to get my git branching to work.

Currently I'm getting this:
[name_of_virtualenv if in one] ~/current/directory () $

How can I get my command prompt to display like this
[name_of_virtualenv if in one] ~/current/directory [master] $

bashrc file:

```
# external settings
# for path in /etc/bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/bash/bashrc; do
#     [[ -f "$path" ]] && . "$path"
# done

# load rvm function
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

# source brew
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi

# history storage settings
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
export HISTSIZE=1000000
export HISTFILESIZE=1000000
export EDITOR='vim'

SEND_256_COLORS_TO_REMOTE=1

# bash_prompt
# The various escape codes that we can use to color our prompt.
        RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
     YELLOW="\[\033[1;33m\]"
      GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
       BLUE="\[\033[1;34m\]"
  LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
LIGHT_GREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
      WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
 LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
 COLOR_NONE="\[\e[0m\]"

 # Detect whether the current directory is a git repository.
 function is_git_repository {
   git branch > /dev/null 2>&1
 }

 # Determine the branch/state information for this git repository.
 function set_git_branch {
   # Capture the output of the "git status" command.
   git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"

   # Set color based on clean/staged/dirty.
   if [[ ${git_status} =~ "working directory clean" ]]; then
     state="${GREEN}"
   elif [[ ${git_status} =~ "Changes to be committed" ]]; then
     state="${YELLOW}"
   else
     state="${LIGHT_RED}"
   fi

   # Set arrow icon based on status against remote.
   remote_pattern="# Your branch is (.*) of"
   if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${remote_pattern} ]]; then
     if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} == "ahead" ]]; then
       remote="↑"
     else
       remote="↓"
     fi
   else
     remote=""
   fi
   diverge_pattern="# Your branch and (.*) have diverged"
   if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${diverge_pattern} ]]; then
     remote="↕"
   fi

   # Get the name of the branch.
   branch_pattern="^# On branch ([^${IFS}]*)"
   if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${branch_pattern} ]]; then
     branch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
   fi

   # Set the final branch string.
   BRANCH="${state}(${branch})${remote}${COLOR_NONE} "
 }

 # Return the prompt symbol to use, colorized based on the return value of the
 # previous command.
 function set_prompt_symbol () {
   if test $1 -eq 0 ; then
       PROMPT_SYMBOL="\$"
   else
       PROMPT_SYMBOL="${LIGHT_RED}\$${COLOR_NONE}"
   fi
 }

 # Determine active Python virtualenv details.
 function set_virtualenv () {
   if test -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ; then
       PYTHON_VIRTUALENV=""
   else
       PYTHON_VIRTUALENV="${BLUE}[`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`]${COLOR_NONE} "
   fi
 }

 # Set the full bash prompt.
 function set_bash_prompt () {
   # Set the PROMPT_SYMBOL variable. We do this first so we don't lose the
   # return value of the last command.
   set_prompt_symbol $?

   # Set the PYTHON_VIRTUALENV variable.
   set_virtualenv

   # Set the BRANCH variable.
   if is_git_repository ; then
     set_git_branch
   else
     BRANCH=''
   fi

   # Set the bash prompt variable.
   PS1="${PYTHON_VIRTUALENV}${YELLOW}\w${COLOR_NONE} ${BRANCH}${PROMPT_SYMBOL} "
 }

 # Tell bash to execute this function just before displaying its prompt.
 PROMPT_COMMAND=set_bash_prompt

pwdtail () { #returns the last 2 fields of the working directory
    pwd|awk -F/ '{nlast = NF -1;print $nlast"/"$NF}'
}

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:~/bin:$PATH
export LS_COLORS='no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.ogg=01;35:*.mp3=01;35:*.wav=01;35:'
export EDITOR='vim'

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.envs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got it working the way I want by changing the command prompt code to the following in my bashrc file:

```
# bash_prompt
# The various escape codes that we can use to color our prompt.
        RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
     YELLOW="\[\033[1;33m\]"
      GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
       BLUE="\[\033[1;34m\]"
  LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
LIGHT_GREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
      WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
 LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
 COLOR_NONE="\[\e[0m\]"

 # Detect whether the current directory is a git repository.
 function is_git_repository {
   git branch > /dev/null 2>&1
 }

 function set_git_branch {
   # Set the final branch string
   BRANCH=`parse_git_branch`
   local TIME=`fmt_time` # format time for prompt string
 }

 function parse_git_branch() {
   git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/\1$(parse_git_dirty)/"
 }

 function parse_git_dirty() {
   [[ $(git status 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != *"working directory clean"* ]] && echo "*"
 }

 fmt_time () { #format time just the way I likes it
     if [ `date +%p` = "PM" ]; then
         meridiem="pm"
     else
         meridiem="am"
     fi
     date +"%l:%M:%S$meridiem"|sed 's/ //g'
 }

 # Return the prompt symbol to use, colorized based on the return value of the
 # previous command.
 function set_prompt_symbol () {
   if test $1 -eq 0 ; then
       PROMPT_SYMBOL="\$"
   else
       PROMPT_SYMBOL="${LIGHT_RED}\$${COLOR_NONE}"
   fi
 }

 # Determine active Python virtualenv details.
 function set_virtualenv () {
   if test -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ; then
       PYTHON_VIRTUALENV=""
   else
       PYTHON_VIRTUALENV="${BLUE}[`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`]${COLOR_NONE} "
   fi
 }

 # Set the full bash prompt.
 function set_bash_prompt () {
   # Set the PROMPT_SYMBOL variable. We do this first so we don't lose the
   # return value of the last command.
   set_prompt_symbol $?

   # Set the PYTHON_VIRTUALENV variable.
   set_virtualenv

   # Set the BRANCH variable.
   if is_git_repository ; then
     set_git_branch
   else
     BRANCH=''
   fi

   # Set the bash prompt variable.
   PS1="${PYTHON_VIRTUALENV}${YELLOW}\w${COLOR_NONE} ${BRANCH}${PROMPT_SYMBOL} "
 }

 # Tell bash to execute this function just before displaying its prompt.
 PROMPT_COMMAND=set_bash_prompt
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to set my prompt the way I want.

Comment: I did a small change to avoid some bash errors. I changed *fmt_time* first line to: **datevar=´date +%p´; if [ -n $datevar ] && [ "$datevar" = "PM" ]; then**

Answer (score -2):

for simplicity, to show git prompt and virtual env you just need this:

```
export PS1="\[\033[1;31m\]`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"` $(__git_ps1 "(git:%s)")"
```