# How to have both conda env and git branch within command line prompt?

Tags: linux, bash, git, anaconda, zsh

[How to set PS1 that make both git and conda can show in the bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973417/how-to-set-ps1-that-make-both-git-and-conda-can-show-in-the-bash)
[Bash command prompt with virtualenv and git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399183/bash-command-prompt-with-virtualenv-and-git-branch)

I've found the following about how to do this in **bash** shell but i'm using **zsh** within macosx. Would this work the same way using zsh? I have the following in my ~/.zshrc

```sh
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/carlos/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/blah/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/blah/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/blah/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

I tried using this link, https://medium.com/pareture/simplest-zsh-prompt-configs-for-git-branch-name-3d01602a6f33, but it doesn't contain the git branch information. Could someone expand on this so the git branch info is included?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Disable automatic modification of the command prompt (PS1) by conda

With conda already installed, run the following command in the termial:

```bash
conda config --set changeps1 false
```

or simply add `changeps1: false` to the `~\.condarc` file. This will disable the automatic modification of the prompt by conda.

#### 2. Modify prompt to display conda env and branch

Next, open `~\.zshrc` with any text editor, and add the following code at the bottom of the file:

```bash
# Determines prompt modifier if and when a conda environment is active
precmd_conda_info() {
  if [[ -n $CONDA_PREFIX ]]; then
      if [[ $(basename $CONDA_PREFIX) == "anaconda3" ]]; then
        # Without this, it would display conda version. Change to miniconda3 if necessary
        CONDA_ENV="(base) "
      else
        # For all environments that aren't (base)
        CONDA_ENV="($(basename $CONDA_PREFIX)) "
      fi
  # When no conda environment is active, don't show anything
  else
    CONDA_ENV=""
  fi
}

# Display git branch
function parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/[\1]/p'
}

# Run the previously defined function before each prompt
precmd_functions+=(precmd_conda_info)

# Define colors
COLOR_CON=$'%F{141}'
COLOR_DEF=$'%f'
COLOR_USR=$'%F{247}'
COLOR_DIR=$'%f'
COLOR_GIT=$'%F{215}'

# Allow substitutions and expansions in the prompt
setopt prompt_subst

PROMPT='${COLOR_CON}$CONDA_ENV${COLOR_USR}%n ${COLOR_DIR}%1~ ${COLOR_GIT}$(parse_git_branch)${COLOR_DEF}$ '
```

#### 3. Apply changes

In the terminal, run `source ~/.zshrc`

#### 4. References

Original code to modify conda env prompt display settings:
[how to modify the anaconda environment prompt in zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656045/how-to-modify-the-anaconda-environment-prompt-in-zsh)

Original code to display git branch:
[Add Git Branch Name to Terminal Prompt](https://gist.github.com/reinvanoyen/05bcfe95ca9cb5041a4eafd29309ff29)